# Android - How can clickable button when parsing process

Tags: android, multithreading

i have i button and one flipperview in my layout. 
When start the activity, activity is parsing a xml. But sometimes this process is take so long time. And i cant click the button while parsing continue.

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            getJSONFromUrl("getVitrinSliderJSON.php?");

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }.start();


    /*****
     * Start Set Main Page Buttons
     */
    Button btnkesfet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ana_btn_kesfet);
    btnkesfet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyAntalyaActivity.this,
                    KesfetAnasayfa.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        jParse(jObj);

        SetFlipper();

    };
};
```

Comment: try AsyncTask, theres lots of examples if you do little googling.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Boolean Varaible for prevent user to click on button during xml Parsing and
use  [button.setEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) for disable or enable button after Parsing

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to put `jParse(jObj);` inside the thread you have to avoid locking up the UI thread.